# Apache Geode in 15 minutes pulse site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: geode

On a local machine I download a fresh install of Geode 1.13 and run through [Apache Geode in 15 minutes or less](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/14/getting_started/15_minute_quickstart_gfsh.html) with default settings. After the install, step 2 start a locator works fine, but when I try step 3 `start pulse` which opens Chrome at https://localhost:7070/pulse I get the error

This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

[image]

I have tried switching off local firewalls and get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Per [start locator](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/113/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/start.html#topic_591260CF25D64562A0EDD7260D2AC6D4) I had to add the `--http-service-bind-address=localhost` or `--http-service-bind-address=127.0.0.1` and then in Chrome make sure I was pointing to http address `http://127.0.0.1:7070/pulse` and the screen came up.

[image]